# Shorten Table Plot X Labels

Tags: r

I have a table barplot (basic table with counts of each level for a factor) where the category names along the x axis are longer than I would like them to be. This is true even after making them perpendicular and adjusting the margins.

How can I shorten either these labels or each catagory name in the table to be only the first n characters?

**Example:**
How would make the labels for: `barplot(table(factor(c("azzzz", "bzzzz", "bzzzz", "czzzz"))))` be a,b, and c.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean...can you just replace them with something like `substr(<category names>,1,n)`? An example would help...

Comment: @joran: That sounds reasonable, not sure how to apply substr to labels on a plot though.

Comment: Labels have got to come from somewhere in your data. A column, row names of a data frame, etc. Change those and the plot should change. Some sample data and your plotting code would make it much clearer.

Comment: @joran: Edited post with an example.

Comment: Changing the data itself would be okay, but just altering the labels in the plot would probably be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take substrings of the vector you are passing to `table`:

```
barplot(table(substr(c("azzzz", "bzzzz", "bzzzz", "czzzz"),1,1)))
```

**EDIT**

Now that I think about it, you probably need the full strings for `table` to match them up correctly. In which case maybe split it into separate steps:

```
tbl <- table(c("azzzz", "bzzzz", "bzzzz", "czzzz"))
names(tbl) <- substr(names(tbl),1,1)
barplot(tbl)
```

You can also pass them directly into `barplot`:

```
barplot(...,names.arg = substr(...,1,1))
```

Comment: Ah, `names.arg` with substr is perfect.